# SQL Unique Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, csv

I have a file that updates every 15 min with sales data. The files is MTD and as of 8 AM it is finalized every day. Its a flat text CSV written to a SP every 15 min. This being said I would like to add the entries to a SQL data based for long term storage. The problem is if I keep adding the table I continue to get duplicates. There are a maximum of 1500 entries per day. I am really new to SQL so the simplest solution would be preferred over potential performance loss until I get some SQL under my wings.

I have SQL 2014 and SSIS. Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated. I read a few of the other posts but nothing that I could find helped this specific issue.

How can I do this?

Comment: is csv file going to have all the entries for all days or it will be different one for each day?

Comment: The problem is if I keep adding the table I continue to get duplicates, this can be tackle by only adding new records right?insert into tableA select from tableB where not exists (tableA.id = tableB.id)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are going to append entries every day to the CSV , you can always truncate the table and bulk insert every day.

Instead of Updates, it is faster and efficient to do truncate and insert.

```
TRUNCATE table myTable

BULK
INSERT myTable
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,  -- in case your csv file has header, other wise you can remove this.
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

It would be good to have a separate CSV file for each day so processing would be faster, in case of single CSV file, it might become too big to handle after a while.

In this case, we can do bulk insert to a staging table and then merge to the actual table.

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('StagingData') IS NULL)
CREATE TABLE StagingData
(  
        abc int,
        ..
)

TRUNCATE table StagingData

BULK
INSERT StagingData
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Now merge this StagingData to your actual table.